# Angular JS ng Grid Default global configurations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am creating a new application using Angular JS where ng grid used at many pages.  I want to enable some global configuration for all the grid so that I can change the look and feel from a common place for all grids like, allow sorting, re-size of columns etc.

Below thread is explaining a bit about this, I would appreciate if someone can provide a more details with some code examples.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/249

I want to implement all global configuration in such a way that if user is not defining any of the configuration then it picks up from global configuration.

I want to define them just after the route configuration. so the same for datepickerConfig, how can I do the same for ngGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it this way:

Wrap your grid controllers in a parent controller that holds variables for global grid configuration.

```
    <div ng-controller="GridGlobals">
        <h1>Grid 1</h1>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1"></div>
        </div>

        <h1>Grid 2</h1>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your individual grid options set the options you want to control globally to the variables stored in the globalGridConfig controller. Since this one wraps the gridcontrollers the variables there are inherited to the scope of the gridcontrollers.

```
        Gridtest.controller('GridGlobals', function ($scope) {
            $scope.GLobGridShowFilter = true;
            $scope.GLobGridShowFooter = true;
        });

        Gridtest.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [
                {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}
            ];

            $scope.gridOptions1 = {
                data: 'myData',
                showFilter: $scope.GLobGridShowFilter,
                showFooter: $scope.GLobGridShowFooter
            }

        });


        Gridtest.controller('MyCtrl2', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [
                {name: "Tom", age: 50},
                {name: "Sue", age: 43},
                {name: "Jack", age: 27},
                {name: "Willy", age: 29},
                {name: "Josh", age: 34}
            ];


            $scope.gridOptions2 = {
                data: 'myData',
                showFilter: $scope.GLobGridShowFilter,
                showFooter: false
            }
        });
```

Since the ng-grid cdns are currently not reachable via my computer I can't provide you with a plunker. Keep me informed if this works for you. I can create a Plunker Demo as soon as this works again.

**Update:**

Hey, it's up again! Here is the promised [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HAzfHk?p=preview)

See, no rtfm-bs, just plain angular magick.

**Update 2:**

This will be a lengthy answer again:-)

I don't think there is a way to define a global scope without some tricks. It' simply not in the ngGrid code and you won't find any answer to this in the documentation nor in the sourcecode.

But here is a different approach:

Add a new object to the $rootScope, this is will be available throughout your app.

```
        Gridtest.run(function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.gridOptionsGlobal = function () {
                this.data = 'myData';
                this.showFilter = true;
                this.showFooter = true;
            }
        })
```

Then in your controllers define your gridOptions like this:

```
        Gridtest.controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [
                {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}
            ];

            $scope.gridOptions = new $scope.gridOptionsGlobal();
        });


        Gridtest.controller('MyCtrl2', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myOtherData = [
                {name: "Tom", age: 50},
                {name: "Sue", age: 43},
                {name: "Jack", age: 27},
                {name: "Willy", age: 29},
                {name: "Josh", age: 34}
            ];

            $scope.gridOptions = new $scope.gridOptionsGlobal();
            //overwiting global settings here
            $scope.gridOptions.data = 'myOtherData';
            $scope.gridOptions.showFooter = false;
        });
```

This way you don't need the wrapper controller in your html.

Of course you can still put the globals to a controller instead of the $rootScope, to prevent overhead on pages where you don't have a grid.

Here's the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RhP7fn?p=preview)

I don't think you can get it more convenient than this.

Comment: Hey Maingay, thnkas for ur post. Your answer is very much close to what I want to achieve. But I am bit more lazy and want to apply global configuration at a single place. Once we have defined the global configuration I want to developer need not to redefine them. I ur case I can see that you have defined the configuration in parent controller but still we need to assign these values for grid defined in child controller. Can we implement in such a way that if we do not define the configuration in parent controller then it picks up those configurations from global.

Comment: I want to implement it in same way we can do for datepickerPopupConfig. I have defined all datepickerPopupConfig just after the ngRoute configuration and now they are applicable to whole application.

Comment: Hey Maingay, last update is really a great help for me. You saved my hours. This is exactly I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help you. The Nick is mainguy btw. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you look through the code, you will find:

`self.config = $.extend(defaults, window.ngGrid.config, options);`

I'm not sure when this was available, but it is available in the latest release at time of writing (2.0.11) at line `1504`.
So in your `config` or `run` you can specify:

`window.ngGrid.config = {
  enablePinning: true
};`

Comment: that's nice Brett!!, seems more clean. will definitely try this.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this [ng-grid module](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) for the grid layout. and yes you can specify with this ng grid module some your global gridding!

Comment: I gone through whole document then only asked this question. That document is not providing good details about global default configuration. Its only about customization at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

as Lalit Sachdeva said, you have the [Getting Started](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) source but you also have their Github [wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki) page that has more advanced features to offer you like: Configuration Options,Defining Columns,Templating your Rows and Cells,Column Sorting and Filtering ,Grid Events etc.