# How to Create an ng-grid from another ng-grid in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid like:

```
$scope.Users = [
    { userID: '1', userName: 'Kan' },
    { userID: '2', userName: 'Kumar' }
];

$scope.userGrid = {
    data: 'Users',
    plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],
    showFooter: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'userID', displayName: 'UserID' },
        { field: 'userName', displayName: 'UserName' }
    ]
};
```

Now I want to create another ng-grid from my rendered grid. Is it possible?

Comment: Look at my lengthy answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008491/nested-ng-grids/24010739#24010739

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want nested grid. I just copy the object obj such grid to create another grid. But how?

Comment: You mean like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/lDSjjHA9SLczHiMgQtQb?p=preview or in different Controllers?

Comment: Thanks. Your concept is similar to mine. But I want create it dynamically with plugin. In plugin I have such grid but how do I create another from it. In plugin I just need such grid definition without data.

Comment: Hmm, I still don't get what you want. Last suggestion is not my concept, it's how angular works. You don't copy anything in the DOM. Maybe you are talking about a global configuration? Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630928/angular-js-ng-grid-default-global-configurations/23650650#23650650

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to get definition of a grid?